# SDK manager path

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk

I want SDK path for unity so I open SDK manager through android studio .i copied the path and paste in unity prefrences-> SDK.then I tired to build and run but it shows this error

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the Android SDK path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

    stderr[
Error:Invalid command android
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

so I tried to open SDK manager manually which is present in this path C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk..
but it is also not running...:(